# How can I fix "payment cannot be completed. Please contact the card issuer

Tags: velo

how can you add and connect payment for debit or credit cards using Wix if you are in Africa?.. And also how can you solve "the payment has is not allowed by the card issuer" error in paypal

Answer (score 0):

for later question, you can't control it's in third party hand